# Access route parameters in Nancy.net in a hook before route invokation

Tags: nancy

Inside of my bootstrapper I have:

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines) {
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline (ctx =>
        {
            var parameters = ctx.Parameters;
            var resolver = ctx.ResolvedRoute;
            return null;
        });
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that when making a request on an url like "http://localhost:3579/thingy/123", which matches a route "/thingy/{thingyId}" both ctx.Parameters and ctx.ResolvedRoute are null, even in AddItemToEndOfPipeline.

Don't ask me why, but I need to do come fiddling using this route parameter before many different sub routes, but can't find a way to access it. Anyone know a way?

Answer (score 2):

I did it :)

```
protected override void ApplicationStartup(Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines) {
    base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
    pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline (ctx =>
        {
            var resolver = container.Resolve<IRouteResolver>();
            var route = resolver.Resolve(ctx);
            var thingyId = route.Parameters["thingyId"];
            return null;
        });
}
```